# How to pass variable in regex-Java to make a script dynamic?

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I have this function written in Java-Selenium and wondering how I can pass a variable(key) in place of evar90? Your support will be appreciated a lot.

```
public void verifyXyz(String key,String expectedResult) {
    selenium.waitForPageLoad();
    String resultString = selenium.executeJSCall("localStorage.getItem('s.tl-data')");
    String matchedString = "";
    String variable = "key";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(eVar90=[^:]*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(resultString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        matchedString = matcher.group();
    }

    Assert.assertTrue("Product variable does not match expected value \n"
                    + "Expected: " + expectedResult + " \n"
                    + "Actual: " + matchedString
            , matchedString.equals(expectedResult));
}
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + key + "=[^:]*)");

Comment: @chptr-one, thank you so much. It's working fine.

Comment: The most important thing is that you should understand why it works. The `Pattern` initialized with usual string. You can handle a pattern like any string: make a concatenation, replacement symbols, take a substring, etc. You can form your regex pattern string as you like.